# Why parent rows do not extend across the entire width

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a simple table in Vue.js and with Bootstrap. After clicking the arrow, the child row is displayed, I would like the child row to be displayed below the parent row. Which i solved by setting
`display:flexbox; flex-direction:column;`

HTML table:
`

```
        <thead>
          <tr> 
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Gender</th>
            <th scope="col">Ability</th>
            <th scope="col">Minimal distance</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight</th>
            <th scope="col">Born</th>
            <th scope="col">In space since</th>
            <th scope="col">Beer consumption (l/y)</th>
            <th scope="col">Knows the answer?</th>
            <th scope="col">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="parent" v-for="item in data" :key="item.data.ID">
            <td>
              <button class="bg-transparent" @click="toggleChildren(item)"><i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td>{{ item.data.ID }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data.Gender }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data.Ability }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data['Minimal distance'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data.Weight }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data.Born }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data['In space since'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data['Beer consumption (l/y)'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.data['Knows the answer?'] }}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeItem(item,null)">Remove</button>
            </td>
            <template v-if="item.children && item.children.has_nemesis && Array.isArray(item.children.has_nemesis.records) && item.children.has_nemesis.records.length && item.childrenVisible">
          <tr  v-for="child in item.children.has_nemesis.records" :key="child.data.ID">
            <td scope="row">{{ child.data.ID }}</td>
            <td class="">{{ child.data['Character ID'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ child.data['Is alive?'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ child.data.Years }}</td>
            <td>
              <button @click="toggleChildren(child)" ><i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button @click="removeItem(child, item)">Remove</button>
           </td>
            <template v-if="child.childrenVisible">
          <tr  v-for="secret in child.children.has_secrete.records" :key="secret.data.ID">
            <td >{{ secret.data.ID }}</td>
            <td >{{ secret.data['Nemesis ID'] }}</td>
            <td >{{ secret.data['Secrete Code'] }}</td>
          </tr>
          </template>
          </tr>
          </template>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  
    </div>`
```

However, this caused the parent rows to not extend the full length of the row(see image)
[image: How the table looks]

CSS:

```
table {
    border: 5px solid red !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
 
thead{
    border: 5px solid blue;
    
}
tbody{
    border: 5px solid green;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 8px; 
}
.parent{
    border: 1px solid brown;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); 
    grid-gap: 8px; 
}
td{
    border: 5px solid black;
    
}
```

[image: How it looks now]

Comment: I love that Zaphod has an entry for each head.  However, I think you actually want display: grid; in this case.

Comment: @Myykro For which element should I display grid?

Comment: You're mostly there.  If you add a class to each element in a column and give that class a standard width it should line up your elements like you want.

Comment: Can you give me example how you think it? I don't know if I understand to you

Comment: For example everything in the Name column you would give the class "col1" and then assign a width to that class.  Do that for all of the columns and your data should line up nicely.

Comment: Something like this? <th class="col1" scope="col">ID</th> <td class="col1">{{ item.data.Name }}</td> then in css .col1{
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: Yep.  You might need to play around with the actual widths but that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `flex` in the table. You can use [`table-layout: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout). Since the table is relatively complex you could use `id` on the headers and `headers` for the rows. Like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th id="col"></th>
            <th id="id">ID</th>
            <th id="name">Name</th>
            <th id="gender">Gender</th>
            <th id="ability">Ability</th>
            <th id="min-distance">Minimal distance</th>
            <th id="weight">Weight</th>
            <th id="born">Born</th>
            <th id="in-space-since">In space since</th>
            <th id="beer-consumption">Beer consumption (l/y)</th>
            <th id="answer">Knows the answer?</th>
            <th id="action">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="parent" v-for="item in data" :key="item.data.ID">
            <td headers="col">
                <button class="bg-transparent" @click="toggleChildren(item)"><i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td headers="id">{{ item.data.ID }}</td>
            <td headers="name">{{ item.data.Name }}</td>
            <td headers="gender">{{ item.data.Gender }}</td>
            <td headers="ability">{{ item.data.Ability }}</td>
            <td headers="min-distance">{{ item.data['Minimal distance'] }}</td>
            <td headers="weight">{{ item.data.Weight }}</td>
            <td headers="born">{{ item.data.Born }}</td>
            <td headers="in-space-since">{{ item.data['In space since'] }}</td>
            <td headers="beer-consumption">{{ item.data['Beer consumption (l/y)'] }}</td>
            <td headers="answer">{{ item.data['Knows the answer?'] }}</td>
            <td headers="action">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeItem(item,null)">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then use `thead th:nth-child(n)` to set the widths for the column. Here's a start for you.

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 12%;
}

thead th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(7) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(8) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(9) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(10) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(11) {
  width: 8%;
}

thead th:nth-child(12) {
  width: 8%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```